# How to use multiple classes in hackerearth problems

Tags: java

I was solving a question of hackerearth in eclipse. As it contains different cases I made two separate classes and they are working fine but as I copied both classes on hackerearth editor, its showing this error

21: error: class Challenge2 is public, should be declared in a file named Challenge2.java

Comment: Welcome to SO! You will need to provide more information for us to be able to help you. Provide the code that is causing the error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some ide's such as eclipse doesn't mind having more than one PUBLIC classes in one document. However, some ide's prefer only one PUBLIC class per document at a time and put other public classes on their own document files (.java files). I use both netbeans and eclipse. Netbeans throws an error if I declare two or more public classes but eclipse doesn't. So in netbeans I make one class public and other classes default such as class Person and the error goes away. So try on hackerearth editor one class as public and other classes as default and see if the error goes away... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In java there can **only be one public** top-level class per .java file, and public top-level classes must have the same name as the source file.

Include multiple classes in one source file if you wish to bundle related support functionality (internal data structures, support classes, etc) together with the main public class. Note that it is always OK not to do this--the only effect is on the readability (or not) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

the file name must be equal to the class name if it is public

so you should save

```
public class Challenge2
{

}
```

as Challenge2.java